# What does ^> mean in a grep pattern?

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

What does this command do?

```
grep "<[^>]*>" inuux.xml
```

What is searching for?

Comment: Also about this command grep "<[^>/]*>"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be explained like this:

```
<         # A literal "<" character
[^>/]*    # Anything that isn't a ">" or a "/", zero or more times
>         # Followed by a literal ">" character
```

Presumably, this is for matching XML/HTML tags. It certainly isn't the best regex in the world, but it's quick, dirty, and probably works.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expressions -- [always a good decision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)